# Results which are known about ideals of spatial tensor product

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, ideals

I am studying about ideals of spatial (minimal) tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras but I did not find any book/paper in which all the results are given.

> What are some results or folklore which are well known about the ideals(primitive/prime/modular)  of spatial tensor products of $C^{\ast}$-algebras.

To start with, if $A$ or $B$ is exact then closed ideals of spatial tensor product $A \otimes B$ are generated by tensor product of two sided closed ideals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one source I know which "considers ideals of tensor products of $C^*$-algebras" is David McConnell's thesis: [$C_0(X)$-structure in $C^*$-algebras, multiplier algebras and tensor products](http://www.tara.tcd.ie/handle/2262/80336).

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find some results of that flavor in  [Closed ideals and Lie ideals of minimal tensor product of certain C*-algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/closed-ideals-and-lie-ideals-of-minimal-tensor-product-of-certain-calgebras/2B84F973C74E7751E7607BDD06337178) .